Enable scrolling content on sheet modal
I would like to ask about the Sheet modal: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#sheet-modal
The case is as shown in the picture. I created a sheet modal with breakpoints [0, 0.65, 1] with a default breakpoint of 0.65, with the layout as follows:

top: header
mid: content (scrollable list)

The problem is that when the modal is opened with the initial breakpoint set to 0.65, the content cannot be scrolled. The modal has to be at the max/1 breakpoint for the content to be scrollable.
The goal I want to achieve in this case is a layout similar to the comments section in the Instagram app, where even if the modal is opened halfway, the comment list can still be scrolled.


i think as the breakpoints are available, you will not be able to make it scrollable since once you scroll it will extend to higher point of breakpoint or go down to lower breakpoint or close, so imo, i believe you can play around with the modal properties from a service and stop the swipe of the modal and breakpoints once it reaches a specific point then activate it back as it was on a specific action..

To make your content scrollable you can do this workaround:
Main modal code:
<ion-modal #modal [isOpen]="isOpen" [initialBreakpoint]="0.65" [breakpoints]="[0, 65, 1]"
    (willDismiss)="isOpen = false">
    <ng-template>
      <ion-content>
        <inner-content-component></inner-content-component>
      </ion-content>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>

inside your inner-content-component use ion-content again:
<ion-content>
   <div>
     //your modal content here
    </div>
</ion-content>

Note: i did this in my angular application, i dont know if it will work on react in same way.
